# Chrome DevTools (F12) self-closes after 2 seconds

Tags: google-chrome

I'm experience an issue on Windows where inspect or hit F12 to open my dev tools, and it opens for two seconds then closes itself. This seems have started happening after a recent update.

Anyone else experiencing this and / or ideas? I've been forced top develop with Firefox which I don't love.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1474659&q=devtools%20closing&can=2

Answer (score 3):

I started seeing this a few days ago (on Mac OS). Microsoft Edge didn't have this behavior but I restarted it today and now it does, so presumably they rolled forward to a version of Chromium that includes this bug.

Comment: I have same issue with Edge